# Minimum Bootcamp partition size for Windows development

Tags: windows, macbookpro, bootcamp

I am hoping for some advice in partitioning my new MacBook Pro's 500GB drive for software development. If possible I would like to create two partitions with one (the smaller) being used for Windows development, occasionally. I am not sure which Windows OS I will be installing (probably Windows 7). I will also be installing Visual Studio, and several browsers: IE, Safari, Firefox, etc.

This is all in support of using one machine for development across 2-3 OSes.

So, the question is how small can I make this partition? Would 100GB be enough?

I am also getting a Mac mini for Windows development but I want to have an on-the-road option just in case.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

100GB would be more than enough.  I have virtualbox running Windows XP with 15 GB and I have had Visual Studio 2008 installed with comfortable amounts of space left.

Windows 7 though, eats disk space.  I'd say for 32-bit 25GB-30GB should be enough.  For 64-bit though, I'd recommend at least 40GB.